# The remote end hung up unexpectedly while Git push with large files

Tags: git, version-control, github, bitbucket, git-remote

When I try to push to my bitbucket repo, I get the following error. (In fact its the same in GitHub as well).

> Counting objects: 48, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (48/48), 1.95 MiB | 38 KiB/s, done.
>   Total 48 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
>   fatal: recursion detected in die handler
>   Everything up-to-date

Mostly I get another error like

> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Either way PUSH fails. This is only for large files I guess. For smaller changes it works fine. I've updated `http.postBuffer` to 2M and it still doesn't work.

**Important**
I've a 3G connection and an CDMA based EVDO Internet connection. With the **3G connection**, the PUSH and everything else **works FINE**. But with the EVDO I get the above errors. So I'm under the impression that its because of some connection problem with my EVDO or ISP.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with BSNL's EVDO connection. Unfortunately none of the technicians in BSNL were able to help me. So i discarded the connection.

Back to good old wired broadband :D.

Answer (score 15):

usually, remote end hangups are from unauthorized users. but if you can successfully connect that's not the issue.

if you really think it's a file size issue, this is my best suggestion:

the default size at which the git client starts *"chunking"* the request is 1MB. you can change this setting using:

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

this example sets the postBuffer to 500MB. play around with this value and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this issue with bitbucket, increasing the `postBuffer` was likely needed but did not solve the issue.

I was only able to resolve this by using another internet connection.

These are the errors `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` returned:

```
* SSLRead() return error -9820
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
* Closing connection 0
```

and then

```
* SSLWrite() returned error -36
* Closing connection 1
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Hopefully that helps somebody, maybe someone with more knowledge understands those SSL errors?

**Update:**

The issue I had was on an inital `git push` into the repo and since then I have tried the same push into the same bitbucket repo with the original internet connection and it works.

Comment: I was also only able to resolve it by using a different internet connection

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and it was because my push included some large files. Apparently github has a 100MB limit on an individual file size. I removed the large files from my commit and retried git push and it worked. Here's some more information about the size limitations:

https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

Answer (score 1):

When the cause is a huge file and `http.postBuffer` just won't work for you, try switching from http to ssh (i.e. `ssh://git@<your git repository>`).  This will likely get you past your hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have the PRC error, instead it was "client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer", and then "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly". The solution for me was to use nested VPN. I need a VPN connection to the git repo (because it is behind the clients firewall).

I first connect my computer to a completely different VPN. This VPN connection is of type "IPv6, Layer3, UDP". Then I set up a virtual machine, and connecte it with another VPN to the target network. From this virtual machine I can push successfully.