# fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly on initial push to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I've been trying to do my initial push to bitbucket for over an hour now and it will not work.

I've checked out and tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840002/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-push-with-large-files) (and many similar posts), but none of this seems to work.

I haven't been able to try SSH because I can't even get that set up on Bitbucket (I've tried countless times and my keys never work).

Here's what I'm seeing most of the time...

```
Enumerating objects: 1200, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1200/1200), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (864/864), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1200/1200), 236.57 MiB | 35.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 1200 (delta 381), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Or sometimes...(the error message is different)

```
Enumerating objects: 1200, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1200/1200), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (864/864), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1200/1200), 146.46 MiB | 8.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 1200 (delta 382), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 7 Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network unreachable
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Any advice is really welcomed! Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a networking issue, probably on the network you're on. Is it a corporate network perhaps with a proxy?

Comment: No, shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it was just by luck or not, but this seemed to work on the first try:

```
git push -u -4 origin master
```

Comment: That limits git to using IPv4 - probably your network has issues with IPv6